# Disable underlining of files/folders in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, hyperlink, settings, underline

Does anyone know how to disable the weird underlines below files and folders in VSCode?

Things I tried so far:

- start VSCode with --disable-extensions (just to be sure)
- choose a different font
- Setting: Terminal > Integrated > GPU acceleration (on/off/auto)
- Setting: Terminal > Integrated > Enable File Links (on/off)
- Setting: Terminal > Integrated > Show Link Hover (on/off)

Sadly no success so far. Does anyone have an idea?

btw: I am on Linux if that is relevant, VSCode version 1.72.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm stupid. When I changed the shell, I realized this would not happen in bash, so a bit more investigation reveal the cause:

For my zsh I use `alias ls=ls --hyperlink` while for bash I do not. So removing that would fix it. VSCode brings it's own logic to make file names clickable, so you are not loosing out on anything. To keep this in non-VSCode shells, I am now checking for the VSCODE_INJECTION env variable:

```
...
if [[ -z "${VSCODE_INJECTION}" ]]; then                                                                                                                                                 
    # This is for non-vscode terminals
    alias ls='ls --color=tty --group-directories-first -v --hyperlink=auto'                                                                                                             
else
    # this is for VSCode's integrated terminal
    alias ls='ls --color=tty --group-directories-first -v'                                                                                                                              
fi 
...
```